# get Facebook Pages in Windows Phone 7 using C# SDK

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I tried to figure this out using the Windows Phone sample from the Facebook C# SDK page, but have been unsuccessful.

Here's the main code:

```
private void GetPages()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

        fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
                return;
            }

            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
            // returns data and paging from Facebook

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    // Not sure if/how to use the custom classes here
                    //item has .Key and .Value
                    //.Key = data and .Value contains the key/value pais for each of the pages returned
                }

            });
        };

        fb.GetAsync("me/accounts");
    }
```

// Custom Classes

```
public class FacebookPageCollection
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public FacebookPage[] data { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "paging")]
        public FacebookPagePaging paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class FacebookPage
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class FacebookPagePaging
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "previous")]
        public Uri previous { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "next")]
        public Uri next { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what the variable "result" returns:
{"data":[{"name":"value1","access_token":"value2","category":"value3","id":"value4","perms":["ADMINISTER","EDIT_PROFILE","CREATE_CONTENT","MODERATE_CONTENT","CREATE_ADS","BASIC_ADMIN"]},{"name":"value1","access_token":"value2","category":"value3","id":"value4","perms":["ADMINISTER","EDIT_PROFILE","CREATE_CONTENT","MODERATE_CONTENT","CREATE_ADS","BASIC_ADMIN"]}],"paging":{"next":"url"}}

What I'd like to do is retrieve and save details for each page.

I have been trying to figure this out and have looked over a number of other posts on here and elsewhere. I just don't have enough experience to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.
Sri

Comment: As much as I'd like to use the CSharpSDK in my app, I have stuck with the old code that I had. May be I'll figure this out some day.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to understanding how to work with json response in fb c# sdk.

Here is the mapping between Javascript JSON and C# JSON. (Notice there is no DateTime and another complex .net objects as it is not part of the JSON spec found in JSON.org)

```
JsonObject => keyvalue pairs => IDictionary<string, object> / IDictinary<string, dynamic>
JsonArray => array => IList<object> / IList<dynamic>
string => string
number => long/decimal
boolean => bool
```

Here is how you do the actual mapping.

```
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
var data = (IList<object>)result["data"];
foreach(var act in data) {
    var account = (IDictionary<string,object>) act;
    var name = (string)account["name"];
    var accessToken = (string)account["access_token"];
    var id = (string)account["id"];

    // normalize to IList<string> permissions, so it is easier to work without casting.
    var permissions = ((IList<object>)account["perms"]).Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
}
```